# Page break on print only

Tags: html, css

I am producing a web page to display the data from  MySQL database. Currently, one of the tables runs to 86 rows of data and I want to print out the first fifty rows, then page break and print the remainder of the rows with the table headers, but I want the actual web page to display all rows without a break and without the table headers.

Currently I'm using a 'while' statement to count the number of rows printed, while another 'while' to read the data and

```
<div style="page-break-after: always"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

to break the page. The complete code section is below

```
 echo '<section>';
            echo '<h3>Spirits etc.</h3>';
            $lineCounter = 1; // Used for line counter
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Spirit WHERE PAL = 'Y' ORDER BY Product";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $totalCounter = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            $totalCounter++;
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                echo '<table class="TFtable">';
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<th>No.</th><th>Spirits etc.</th><th></th><th>Sulphites >10ppm</th><th>Phenylalanine</th><th>Caffeine<th>Dairy</th><th colspan=3>Cereals containing gluten</th>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    while ($lineCounter < $totalCounter) {
                    
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            
                            if ( $row["None"] == 'None Known' ) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                    echo '<td>' . $lineCounter .'</td>';
                                    echo '<td style="text-align:left">'.$row["Product"].'</td>';
                                    echo '<td colspan =8>'.$row["None"].'</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                                $lineCounter++;
                            } else {
                                echo '<tr>
                                    <td>' . $lineCounter . '</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:left">'.$row["Product"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["None"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["Sulphites"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["Phenylalanine"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["Caffeine"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["Milk"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["CCG_Barley"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["CCG_Wheat"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["CCG_Maize"].'</td>
                                </tr>';
                                $lineCounter++;
                            }
                            if ($lineCounter == 51 or $lineCounter == 101 or $lineCounter == 151 or $lineCounter == 201) {
                                echo '</table>';
                                echo '<div style="page-break-after: always"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></div>';
                                echo '<h4>Spirits etc. cont.</h4>';
                                echo '<table class="TFtable">';
                                echo '<tr>';
                                    echo '<th>No.</th><th>Spirts etc.</th><th></th><th>Sulphites >10ppm</th><th>Phenylalanine</th><th>Caffeine<th>Dairy</th><th colspan=3>Cereals containing gluten</th>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }
                        } 
                    } 
                    echo '</table>';
            } else {
                echo 'No spirit products';
            }
            echo '<div style="page-break-after: always"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></div>';
            echo '</section>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need CSS with media query:

```
@media print {
  .print-page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

And then use `class="print-page-break"` instead of `style="page-break-after: always"`